# Maven multi module project structure in GIT

Tags: git, maven, github, maven-module

I am having issue with the structure of multi module project in git.

So I have my parent project in which I have given modules as all the child project. Build and everything is working fine.

I am trying to maintain a structure like spark/nifi and other apache project where apache -> spark (pom.xml) -> modules (at the same level as the parent spark pom.xml)

But when I am publishing my local repo in git the structure is like organization -> parent (extra folder)-> parent (pom.xml) -> modules(This should be one level back)

A extra folder of parent is getting created in git, what I want is the parent repo just to have pom.xml and all the child modules.

Can some share the structure that I should be using?

Comment: Can you give a link to your project?

Comment: Sorry it's inside a private organization actually.

Comment: Can you make an example project on github it's easier to understand what you want/have work...

Comment: I don't understand "A extra folder of parent is getting created in git". Who creates that folder in git? You? A program?